# Unity Firebase Database не видит успешной авторизации

Tags: unity3d, firebase, firebase-database, google-play-services

Я использую **Unity 5.5.3f1**, **Google Play Services** и **Firebase Unity SDK**, включая Аутентификацию, Базу данных, и Аналитику для игры на андроид. Мне нужно аутентифицировать пользователя через Google Play Services, получить токен и использовать его для Google аутентификации в Firebase. Затем я использую Firebase Database для синхронизации прогресса игрока. Ниже приведены правила доступа к базе данных Firebase

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Все работает, но к сожалению не всегда, иногда я получаю ошибку `Permssion denied` от базы данных, хотя я точно уверен, что авторизация прошла успешно, и что обращение происходит именно к тому узлу базы, который доступен данному пользователю. Я пробовал использовать искусственные задержки между операциями авторизации и доступа к базе (вплоть до 5ти секунд), пробовал производить несколько повторных попыток обращений, после первой неудачной - все это не помогло. Для того чтобы контролировать последовательность операций, я использую корутины вместо `ContinueWith` но думаю это не имеет значения (я пробовал и с `ContinueWith`).

Все операции выполняются в правильной последовательности, сначала авторизация в google play services, затем использование полученного токена для авторизации в firebase (обо всех этих операциях я получаю сообщения об успехе) и только после этого попытки обращения к базе данных, во время которых и происходят ошибки (но повторюсь - не всегда). Изменение правил доступа на полностью публичные помогает, но это конечно же не то, что мне нужно...

Ниже приведен метод, который я использую для получения из базы данных сыграного игроком времени (если оно больше чем локальное - нужно заменить локальный прогресс удаленным, если меньше - нужно заменить удаленный локальным):

```js
 public IEnumerator CheckPlayedTime()
        {
            Debug.Log("Database : Start CheckingPlayedTime");
            if (currentUser == null || rootReference == null)
            {
                Debug.Log("Database :  Can't get timedPlayedInSeconds! CurrentUser or Reference == null!");
                yield break;
            }

            var task = currentUserNode.Child("fullProgress").Child("timePlayedInSeconds").GetValueAsync();
            yield return new WaitUntil(() => task.IsCompleted || task.IsFaulted);

            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.LogErrorFormat("Database :  Can't get timedPlayedInSeconds! {0}",
                    task.Exception.InnerExceptions);
            }
            else if (task.IsCompleted)
            {
                if (task.Result.Exists)
                {
                    long resultPlayedTime = (long) task.Result.GetValue(false);

                    Debug.Log("Database : Played Time Gotten" + resultPlayedTime);
                    playedTime = (int) resultPlayedTime;
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("Database : PlayedTimeNotFound! Will be sent");
                    playedTime = 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

Ниже участок кода, в котором видна последовательность выполнения всех операций с Firebase. Выполнение идет в строгой последовательности, каждая из подпрограмм включает другие подпрограммы и дожидается их полного завершения и только после этого производится переход к следующему пункту. А метод на котором и происходит спотыкание (оно затем происходит и на последующих) приведен выше.

```js
IEnumerator Start() {
  yield
  return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(delayBetweenOperations); //Искусственная задержка
  GooglePlayServicesSystem.instance.Authenticate(); //Делаем попытку авторизации в Google Play Services

  yield
  return new WaitUntil(() => GooglePlayServicesSystem.instance.AuthenticationTrialEnded); //Дожидаемся завершения

  if (GooglePlayServicesSystem.instance.isAuthorized) //Если авторизация прошла успешно
  {
    yield
    return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(delayBetweenOperations); //Искусственная задержка
    var token = GooglePlayServicesSystem.instance.AuthenticationToken; //Получаем токен пользователя
    yield
    return StartCoroutine(FirebaseSystem.instance.Authorize(token)); //Начинаем и дожидаемся окончания авторизации в Firebase

    int playedTime = -1; //Сюда будем записывать сыграное время
    while (playedTime == -1 && attemptsCount < 3) //Повторные попытки получить доступ к данным (если playedTime все еще -1, значит доступ не был получен, пробуем еще)
    {
      yield
      return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(delayBetweenOperations); //Искусственная задержка
      yield
      return StartCoroutine(FirebaseSystem.instance.CheckPlayedTime()); //Начинаем и дожидаемся запроса получения сыгранного времени
      playedTime = FirebaseSystem.instance.playedTime; //Получаем сыгранное время
      attemptsCount++;
    }

    yield
    return StartCoroutine(ProgressSystem.instance.ComparePlayedTime(playedTime)); //Запускаем сравнение времени игры в локальном прогрессе и в базе данных Firebase
    //Если локальное время меньше - запустится загрузка прогресса из базы данных Firebase
    //Если локальнео время больше или не было получено время из базы данных (к примеру его там еще нет) - выполняется отправка прогресса в базу данных
  }

  var loadingOperation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("MainLoading"); //После завершения всех операций - загружаем сцену главной загрузки игры
}
```

И вот еще метод авторизации в firebase после получения токена. Этот метод ВСЕГДА завершается успешно, и в результате авторизации я ВСЕГДА получаю корректный ID пользователя, который я потом использую в качестве части адреса в базе данных (в ветви users, каждому пользователю соответствует его подветвь, именованная его ID

```js
public IEnumerator Authorize(string googleIdToken)
        {
            FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
            Credential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.GetCredential(googleIdToken, null);

            //Начинаем авторизацию
            var task = auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential);
            yield return new WaitUntil(() => task.IsCompleted || task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled);//Дожидаемся окончания или прерывания

            if (task.IsCanceled)//Если операция была прервана
            {
#if DEBUG
                DebugControlled.Log("AuthMethods : SignInWithCredentialAsync was canceled.");
#endif
            }
            else if (task.IsFaulted)//Если авторизация не удалась
            {
#if DEBUG
                DebugControlled.Log("AuthMethods : SignInWithCredentialAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
#endif
            }
            else if (task.IsCompleted)//Если авторизация успешна
            {
                currentUser = task.Result;//Получаем ссылку на текущего пользователя
                if (rootReference != null)
                    currentUserNode = rootReference.Child("users").Child(currentUser.UserId);//Получаем ссылку на его узел в базе данных

#if DEBUG
                DebugControlled.Log(string.Format("AuthMethods : User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
                    currentUser.DisplayName, currentUser.UserId));
#endif
            }
        }
```

Я совершенно не понимаю как такое может быть, и в чем причина периодического отказа в доступе авторизованным пользователям к их ветви базы..

Comment: " я точно уверен, что авторизация прошла успешно" - видимо нет, если "Изменение правил доступа на полностью публичные помогает"

Comment: @ValeraKvip Все сообщения в логе говорят об успешной, и я получаю от авторизации идентификатор пользователя, который я не имею возможности никак получить, кроме как после удачной авторизации, потом с помощью этого же идентификатора обращаюсь к базе данных к одноименному узлу.

Comment: А авторизация в firebase тоже проходит успешно?

Comment: @ValeraKvip да, именно в результате успешной авторизации в firebase я получаю корректный идентификатор пользователя, и затем отправляю запрос к базе данных к его узлу.

Comment: Может быть что обращение к данным, происходит до завершения авторизации, попробуй установить какой то флажок.  На этот вопрос сложно ответить, не типичная проблема, тут поможет только доооолгая отладка.  Ну или опубликуй весь код(работы с firebase) и там, возможно, будет заметна явная ошибка

Comment: @ValeraKvip Чтобы убедиться что попытка обращения к  базе выполняется только после завершения авторизации я использую сопрограммы, в этих запросах уже есть свои флажки (isCompleted, isFaulted, isCancelled), вот одного из них я и дожидаюсь. И опять же, я не могу получить идентификатор пока авторизация не завершится (это как раз отмечается флагом isCompleted). К тому же я добавляю искусственную задержку между этими действиями. Где-то на stackoverflow советовали подобное.

Comment: @ValeraKvip Дооолгой отладкой я как раз и занимаюсь уже доолго :) Но вот все указывает на то, что все должно быть в порядке и удачное стечение обстоятельств ничем не отличается от неудачного с моей стороны судя по логам..

Comment: @ValeraKvip добавил еще один участок кода, в котором видна общая последовательность